# PHP & OCI query returns NUMBER columns as STRING

Tags: php, ajax, numbers, type-conversion, oracle-call-interface

I'm using PHP5 and OCI 8 with Oracle 11g.
When I fetch a row using `oci_fetch_all`, the whole result is converted as `STRING` even for the `NUMBER` columns and even if I use Oracle's `TO_NUMBER` in the query.

What I'm trying to do is simple: the javascript calls the PHP script through an Ajax request. The script just fetch some `NUMBER` data and encode them into JSON. I want the data to be encoded as integer, so the javascript can do math stuff on it (add, divide,..etc) without any conversion.

I am pretty sure that the problem comes from OCI and not JSON encoding because when I `VAR_DUMP` the result of oci_fetch_all, I can clearly see double quotes on every result:

```
{
"COLUMN1":"12",
"COLUMN2":"52"
}
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
{
"COLUMN1":12,
"COLUMN2":52
}
```

I tried to:

- Change the flag of `oci_fetch_all` (`OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW`, `OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN`...)
- Use `oci_fetch_array` instead of `oci_fetch_all`
- Remove the UTF8 encoding on the connexion to oracle (I know, its stupid)

The strange thing is that I can't find any thing on the internet about this problem... It's like nobody faced the same issue. Maybe i'm doing something wrong...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an extra option in json_encode:

```
json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

However this option requires a PHP version of 5.3.3 or higher (thus its ok for you).

Comment: This only works if you want *all* numeric values converted. I have phone numbers that I want to leave as strings (and are strings in the database), but other values that I do want converted...

Answer (score 0):

All database extensions in PHP work like this, there's nothing you can do about it.
You'll have to manually type-cast the database results.

Comment: To expand, I did a bit of work on making it more streamlined so that I didn't have to manually typecast all my columns in PHP from MySQL. It involved running a `DESCRIBE` statement at the top of my page and then storing the values in an array with the PHP-corresponding type. It wasn't *hard*, but it was a bit time consuming. Mine was with MySQL, but if OP would like I could post my code up.

Comment: Yes of course! That would probably be helpful to me! Thanks guys